# Copy of Joomla under same domain - Login Issue

Tags: joomla-3.6

I have created a copy of a joomla website under the same domain. I then edited the new website to be something different from the first. Every website is under it's own folder:

> www.mydomain.com/website1
>
> www.mydomain.com/website2

The issue that i am having is that i cannot be logged in to both sites, if i try to login on the second one i get kicked from the first and vice versa.

Any idea what i should change?

Comment: maybe the second one uses the database of the first and vice versa.

Comment: No every site has its own files and database i just advanced the first site up to a point and created a duplicate so i would not do some basic steps again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Global Configuration and check Cookie Settings. Most probably your cookie settings are same for both domains and they both are sharing same cookies.

[image]

Comment: They are both empty in both websites. Using my example in my question how should i set those?

Comment: User website domain name in the cookie domain field, subdirectory name in cookie path. example ".mydomain.com" (see leading dot) as domain "/website1/" as path.